# jQuery.when(deferreds) or equivalent in ZenDesk App

Tags: javascript, jquery, zendesk

In my ZenDesk app, I:

1. retrieve some identifying information from the ticket and requester
2. make several requests to another web service
3. modify the ticket with the combined results

Using plain jQuery, you'd coordinate this using [jQuery.when(deferreds)](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/) to trigger step 3 once all of the requests in step 2 are complete:

```
$.when($.ajax("/page1"), $.ajax("/page2"))
    .done(function(page1result, page2result) { 
        // modify the ticket with the results
    });
```

1. Is jQuery.when() available in an App? (I tried `this.$.when()` with no luck.)
2. If not, what's the preferred way to accomplish something similar? (Perhaps using [Promises](http://developer.zendesk.com/documentation/apps/reference/promises.html) directly?)

Comment: The ZenDesk App plug-in environment is defined entirely by ZenDesk.  jQuery and Underscore are [included automatically](http://developer.zendesk.com/documentation/apps/migration/introduction.html#use-of-jquery-and-prototype).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`jQuery.when()` is available through the application object as `this.when()`.  Here's a simple example (framework version 0.5) that creates a couple trivial promises (using `this.promise()`, similar to `jQuery.Deferred()`) then waits until they have succeeded/resolved to invoke a third function.

Substitute `this.ajax(...)` for `this.createPromise()` to do real work.

### app.js

```
(function() {
    return {
        onActivate: function() {
            var promises = []

            promises.push(this.createPromise().done(function() {
                console.log('promise 1 done');
            }));

            promises.push(this.createPromise().done(function() {
                console.log('promise 2 done');
            }));

            this.when.apply(this, promises).done(function() {
                console.log('all promises done');
            });
        },

        // returns a promise that always succeeds after 1 sec.
        createPromise: function() {
            return this.promise(function(done, fail) { 
                setTimeout(done, 1000);
            });
        },

        events: {
            'app.activated': 'onActivate'
        }
    };
}());
```